# Dashboard in Dynamics 365 redirecting to PowerBI

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

I have a Dashboard in the left menu of the Dyamics 365 Sales Hub App.

[image]

When I open a PowerBI dashboard (Published in the PowerBI service) it loads up fine.

[image]

The moment I click it or perform some action on the dashboard, a new window pops up and it redirects to PowerBI Service.

[image]

I want to view and do my action in Dynamics itself. This is annoying for the other users. Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried making the dashboard a system dashboard by directly importing it to the Solution.
Making a new dashboard and pinning the report live.